# How to raise exception within a try/except block properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

right now I have a problem where I want to raise a specific TypeError if there is one. However, what ends up happening is the interpreter sees the first error, and then in the middle of handling it it raises the other one as well saying "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"

this is what I have

```
  def function(dictionary)
    try:
        value = max(dictionary.values())
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("some error")
```

I plug in the following into the shell:

```
function({1:'a', 2:3})
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: can you show the code that generated error? the snippet you posted works fine at my side.

Comment: edited just now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discard the exception context, [you can explicitly discard it using `from None`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/), e.g.:

```
try:
    value = max(dictionary.values())
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError("some error") from None
```

That said, it's usually best to leave the context in place; the only time you'll see it is if the exception is uncaught and the default logging occurs, or you try to log the exception (e.g. with `logger.exception`). That additional information is often useful, especially for extremely broad exception types like `TypeError` and `ValueError` (where you intend to catch specific known subtypes, and unexpectedly catch one caused in a completely different way).

To be clear, this only works on Python 3, but then, exception context chaining only *exists* on Python 3; on Python 2, the context is lost automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are raising the exception while handling it, the exception is sent back to the caller function.

If you just want to handle it and print the error and move on with rest of the execution, you can do sth like this

```
except TypeError as t:
    print ("Error", t)
```